# mmap of O_WRONLY opened file

Tags: linux, mmap

SHORT: I can't find a way to `mmap` the `O_WRONLY` opened file.

LONG:  I am looking for the way to write DMA (s/g mode) provided data to disk PARTITION(!) as fast as possible, avoiding kernel buffering. `O_DIRECT` does not work and Linus forbids to use it.
For this I `mmap` each DMA buffer with MAP_FIXED and corresponding offset in the file. But if the file is opened as `O_RDWR`, this causes the kernel to compete with the DMA on filling the input RAM with file data. In most cases kernel wins...:)
So, I need to explain to the kernel, that it shouldn't touch my pages, just write them into the mapped file when I call `msync()`. How?

Comment: Which combination of flags you use for mmap?

Comment: @lonewasp I tried a lot. But the most logical for me looks:
    mmap(TBuf, TSIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_FIXED|MAP_SHARED, fdo, offs)
Actually, any working will be OK...:)